# Expected type 'str' got 'dict[str,str]' instead

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

I am currently following an on-line python tutorial where this program should replace all the alpha-numeric file names in a particular folder to only alphabets.

The guy was using **Version 2** so the string translate method worked out just fine for him. As I'm using **Version 3** I got this "**translate should contain only 1 argument**" error.

Trying to make the program work in Version 3, I used the below code:

```
import os


def rename_files():

    file_list = os.listdir(r"C:\Users\PERSONAL\Desktop\Python projects\prank")
    print(file_list)
    saved_path = os.getcwd()
    os.chdir(r"C:\Users\PERSONAL\Desktop\Python projects\prank")

intab = {
    "0": "", "1": "", "2": "", "3": "", "4": "", "5": "", "6": "", "7": "", "8": "", "9": "",
}

transtab = str.maketrans(intab)

for file_name in file_list:
    os.rename(file_name, file_name.translate(transtab))
    os.chdir(saved_path)
rename_files()
```

Although not sure it would get me the correct output, I'm now stuck with another error "**Expected type 'str' got 'dict[str,str]' instead**" at *str.maketrans(intab)*. Any help or alternate solution would be much appreciated.

Comment: Please don't use a Python 2 tutorial to try to learn Python 3. You're going to run into a bunch of incompatibilities just like this one that will distract you from your true purpose of learning the language. Upgrade your tutorial or downgrade your interpreter, and it will save you a headache.

Comment: I'm confused. You say your error message is `translate should contain only 1 argument`. Then you say it is `Expected type 'str' got 'dict[str,str]' instead`. Which one is it?

Comment: Cannot reproduce.  Defining `intab` as shown and running `str.maketrans(intab)` works fine for me in Python 3.4.3.

Comment: @Kevin: The "translate" error is from the unspecified code from the unspecified tutorial.  The "Expected type" error is (supposedly) from the code shown here.

Comment: @Kevin: For the above given code, Expected type 'str' got 'dict[str,str]' is the error I've got at transtab = str.maketrans(intab).

Comment: [Works on my machine](http://ideone.com/GTuGyI).

Comment: @Kevin, jwodder: It worked out guys! A small error from my end. Thank you for responding though.